# ArrayFormula with IF statement in Google Sheets (includes a TextJoin)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I'm trying to turn a list of names (Col A) into a list of names (Col B) but where Col B inserts an additional row, duplicates one name + "- Date"
(So ultimately I want Column C to be the final output)

Eg.

[image]

To get from the Col A to B - I have used

```
=transpose(split(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),true,A2:A),CHAR(10),true,false))
```

I can transfer B2 into C2 with

```
=if(B2<>"",TextJoin(" - ",false,B2,"Date"),B2)
```

Can anyone help me turn this into an ArrayFormula for the entire column? Or come up with a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
=arrayformula(
    if(B2:B= "", 
       offset(B2:B, -1, 0), 
       concat(B2:B, " - Date")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce("Output_",tocol(A2:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,c&" - Date",c)))
```

[image]